# Is it possible to get insert statements from CQL column family?

Tags: cassandra, export, schema

I have columnfamily testtable with data. Can I somehow export data to INSERT statements?
desc testtable will give me code to create it, but how can I export data? thanks.

Comment: You could `SELECT JSON * FROM source`, then `INSERT INTO target JSON` with the JSON strings that you got as a result from the query?

Comment: Thanks, It's better than nothing, but CQL statements are preferred for me.

Comment: Um, they are CQL statements. Or rather parts of CQL statements. Possibly I am missing your problem here.

Answer (score 4):

If you just want to export from one table to another you can use the CQL COPY command:

```
COPY keyspace.table1(column1, column2) TO 'temp.csv'; 
COPY keyspace.table2(column1, column2) FROM 'temp.csv';
```

This will copy all of the data from keyspace.table1 to keyspace.table2